# Случайный вывод фраз

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть код. Как его изменить, чтобы получился случайный вывод?

```
<?php
//имя сервера
$serverMySql = "localhost";
// логин
$db_log      = "*******";
// пароль
$db_pass     = "*****";
function db_connect($serverMySql, $db_log, $db_pass) //create connection
{
    $r = mysql_connect($serverMySql, $db_log, $db_pass);
    return $r;
}
//база данных
$database = "perecc";

//название таблицы в базе
$table = "article";

//кол-во пользователей на странице
$users_on_page = "100";

//подключаемся
db_connect($serverMySql, $db_log, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($database);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
// страницы
if (empty($_GET["p"])) {
    $_GET["p"] = "1";
}
$p = $_GET["p"];

// защита от ввода  
if (preg_match("/[%a-z_@.,^=:;Р°-СЏ\"*()&$#в„–+\-!?<>\~`|[{}\]]/i", $p)) {
    die(header("Location:sluch_list.php"));
}

// формируем запрос
$count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` from `$table`"));

// считаем страницы
$total = ceil($count / $users_on_page);
if ($p > $total) {
    $p = $total;
}

// формируем запрос
$first  = $p * $users_on_page - $users_on_page;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table` LIMIT $first, $users_on_page");
?>
<?php
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // цикл вывода
    {
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    print "</tr>";
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>$data[0]</td>";
    print "<td>$data[2]</td>";
    print "<td>$data[1]</td>";
    print "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Случайный вывод чего?

Comment: Извините, не объяснил. Вывод из таблицы `$table = "article";` в случайном порядке фразы столбик: `content`. У меня в коде под №2    `print "<td>$data[2]</td>";`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `$table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $first, $users_on_page
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: С ордером ранд - $first нафиг не нужен. Соответственно первый запрос тоже (который должен выглядеть так "SELECT **COUNT**(`id`) from `$table`")

Comment: Если подскажите решение задачки посложнее буду благодарен!
Исходя из моего кода Как сделать вывод фраз "По рейтингу".
Рейтинг у меня в БД  в другой таблице rating_post, колонка up (или по счету $data[1])
____
Фразы:
Таблица article______________
{id} __{timestamp} ___ {content} ___             {author}
______
{19}______{2012-10-20}_______ {Сейчас котам...} ___     {«Автор»}
___
Рейтинг:
Таблица rating_post
id_post       up down 
_____
21        2 0